# Set a callback method in a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, callback, datatemplate

I have a listbox of custom items set through a DataTemplate.

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyMainControl">
    <ListBox x:Name="lbConfigurationList"
          DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ConfListVM.ObservableConfList}"
          SelectionChanged="OnConfigurationSelected"
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:EditableTextBlock Text="{Binding ConfName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

Is it possible to call a method on the control owning this listbox each time someting happens in the EditableTextBlock, through something like:

```
<local:EditableTextBlock Text="{Binding ConfName}" MyNotifyEvent={SomeMyMainControlMethod} />
```

If this is possible, which terms should I search to understand how to setup and launch the event from my DataTemplate's EditableTextBlock?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example using Behaviors:

```
<Window x:Class="TextBlockEventHandlerInDataTemplate.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBlockEventHandlerInDataTemplate"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}" >
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                          <local:ShowMessageOnTextChangedBehavior/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Codebehind, sorry i didn't have time for MVVM approach:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        items.Add("item 1");
        items.Add("item 2");
        items.Add("item 3");
        items.Add("item 4");

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And this should be your class doing the job:

```
public class ShowMessageOnTextChangedBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += AssociatedObjectOTextChanged;
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= AssociatedObjectOTextChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(AssociatedObject.Text);
    }
}
```

The other thing would be to define an attached property. I use both ways, depending on the mood :)

Ah, i was about to forget an important thing: you need to reference

**Microsoft.Expression.Interactions** and **System.Windows.Interactivity** from Expression.Blend.SDK.

Comment: Does base.OnDetaching() calls the method "OnDetaching()" of Window?

Comment: The OnAttached is called when XAML parser parses XAML and creates instance of behaviour and adds this to BehaviorCollection of target control which is exposed as DependencyAttached property and it will be detached on window closing.

Comment: Got it; so the method "AssociatedObjectOTextChanged" is called everytime the event "TextChanged" is raised?

Comment: @user1722791 Sorry for the late response, but yes, that method is called on TextChanged.

Comment: I tried this, but had some difficulties implementing the behaviour. Then I tried the property "Mode=TwoWay", and now I feel so stupid to have not just told before I just needed to update the source text...